# AngularJS - How to render a partial with variables?

Tags: angularjs

For example, I have a partial in `car-list.html`, and I want to render it in several places with different collections of cars.  Maybe something like this:

```
<h1>All New Cars</h1>
<div ng-include="car-list.html" ng-data-cars="allCars | onlyNew"></div>

<h1>All Toyotas</h1>
<div ng-include="car-list.html" ng-data-cars="allCars | make:toyota"></div>
```

The main difference from a normal include is that the partial doesn't need to know anything about which list of cars it's displaying.  It's given an array of cars, and it displays them. Possibly like:

```
<!-- car-list.html -->
<div ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-controller="CarListControl">
    {{car.year}} {{car.make}} {{car.model}}
</div>
```

Comment: You should use a directive for that. It's been made to do exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: A solution is create a new directive, as i said in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36916276/2516399

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This directive provides 2-way data-binding between the parent scope and renamed "local" variables in the child scope. It can be combined with other directives like `ng-include` for awesome template reusability. Requires AngularJS 1.2.x

## jsFiddle: [AngularJS - Include a partial with local variables](http://jsfiddle.net/colllin/eJP7r/)

---

### The Markup

```
<div with-locals locals-cars="allCars | onlyNew"></div>
```

**What's going on:**

- This is basically an extension of the `ngInclude` directive to allow you to pass **renamed** variables in from the parent scope. `ngInclude` is NOT required at all, but this directive has been designed to work well with it.
- You can attach any number of `locals-*` attributes, which will all be parsed & watched for you **as Angular expressions**.

  - Those expressions become available to the included partial, attached as properties of a `$scope.locals` object.
  - In the example above, `locals-cars="..."` defines an expression that becomes available as `$scope.locals.cars`.
  - Similar to how a `data-cars="..."` attribute would be available via jQuery using `.data().cars`

---

### The Directive

**EDIT** I've refactored to make use of (and be independent of) the native `ngInclude` directive, and move some of the calculations into the compile function for improved efficiency.

```
angular.module('withLocals', [])
.directive('withLocals', function($parse) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        compile: function(element, attributes, transclusion) {
            // for each attribute that matches locals-* (camelcased to locals[A-Z0-9]),
            // capture the "key" intended for the local variable so that we can later
            // map it into $scope.locals (in the linking function below)
            var mapLocalsToParentExp = {};
            for (attr in attributes) {
                if (attributes.hasOwnProperty(attr) && /^locals[A-Z0-9]/.test(attr)) {
                    var localKey = attr.slice(6);
                    localKey = localKey[0].toLowerCase() + localKey.slice(1);

                    mapLocalsToParentExp[localKey] = attributes[attr];
                }
            }

            var updateParentValueFunction = function($scope, localKey) {
                // Find the $parent scope that initialized this directive.
                // Important in cases where controllers have caused this $scope to be deeply nested inside the original parent
                var $parent = $scope.$parent;
                while (!$parent.hasOwnProperty(mapLocalsToParentExp[localKey])) {
                    $parent = $parent.$parent;
                }

                return function(newValue) {
                    $parse(mapLocalsToParentExp[localKey]).assign($parent, newValue);
                }
            };

            return {
                pre: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {

                    // setup `$scope.locals` hash so that we can map expressions
                    // from the parent scope into it.
                    $scope.locals = {};
                    for (localKey in mapLocalsToParentExp) {

                        // For each local key, $watch the provided expression and update
                        // the $scope.locals hash (i.e. attribute `locals-cars` has key
                        // `cars` and the $watch()ed value maps to `$scope.locals.cars`)
                        $scope.$watch(
                            mapLocalsToParentExp[localKey],
                            function(localKey) {
                                return function(newValue, oldValue) {
                                    $scope.locals[localKey] = newValue;
                                };
                            }(localKey),
                            true
                        );

                        // Also watch the local value and propagate any changes
                        // back up to the parent scope.
                        var parsedGetter = $parse(mapLocalsToParentExp[localKey]);
                        if (parsedGetter.assign) {
                            $scope.$watch('locals.'+localKey, updateParentValueFunction($scope, localKey));
                        }

                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Also useful without `ng-include`. For example, if you want to display a filtered list along with the count of filtered or unfiltered items. `<span with-locals locals-filtered-list="myList | filter:'a query'"> MATCHED {{locals.filteredList.length}} ITEM(S): <span ng-repeat="item in locals.filteredList">{{item.name}}</span></span>`

Comment: JSFiddle link is broken.

Comment: I can't get this to work with AngularJS 1.1.5. The local I pass in appears to be undefined in the included template, even though it is defined and has properties in the scope when I use the `div` with `with-locals`.

Comment: @SarahVessels - I found 2 bugs that I fixed today, please try again if you were having trouble before.  It no longer assumes a `$parent` relationship between the two scopes -- sometimes other directives or controllers can cause this scope to be nested deeper than one level. Also there was a JS namespacing issue that caused local variables to overwrite each other.

Comment: $parent.hasOwnProperty will fail for me as $parent can be null.  Any idea why this may be?

Comment: @Dave Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Dave That error appears if, for example, you specify `locals-cars="madMaxCollection"` but `madMaxCollection` isn't available anywhere in the `$scope` ancestry. Possibly (a) there was a typo, or (b) the variable hasn't been defined yet in the parent scope, or (c) there is an isolate scope somewhere.  Maybe I should update to allow passing variables that haven't been defined in the parent scope?

Answer (score 25):

You can achieve that easily with a `directive`.

Something like that:

```
angular.module('myModule')
.directive('cars', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { 'cars': '=data' },
    template: "<div ng-repeat='car in cars'>\n" +
    "  {{car.year}} {{car.make}} {{car.model}}\n" +
    "</div>"
  };
});
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
<h1>All New Cars</h1>
<cars data="allCars | onlyNew"></cars>

<h1>All Toyotas</h1>
<cars data="allCars | make:toyota"></cars>
```

You can find more info about directives [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: So, it's possible, but i have to create a directive every time I want to do it?  Seems pretty verbose...  Is there a way to dynamically specify the template and the variable name(s)?  Maybe by specifying a data object?  `ng-data="{cars: {{allCars | onlyNew}}, templateUrl: 'car-list.html'}"`

Comment: It depends. If you want to create a short piece of dynamic HTML that you want to embed here and there, directives are perfect. If you want to load a big template, like a menu, you can use `include` and give your template a controller. Then you get the data you need with that controller (through services, resources or whatever and assign them in the `$scope`).

Comment: But one directive must achieve only one thing. You cannot give it a dynamic template. Moreover most of the time directives also have a `controller` or `link` function, that are specific.

Comment: FYI it IS possible to have a more generic solution.  See my answer

Comment: Wow, I finally understand what extending directives is good for. This is very powerful, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to offer [my solution](http://tech.fongmun.com/post/131863914487/scoping-variables-in-ng-include-without-ng-repeat), which is in a different design.

The ideal usage for you is:

```
<div ng-include-template="car-list.html" ng-include-variables="{ cars: (allCars | onlyNew) }"></div>
```

ng-include-variables's object is added to the local scope. Therefore, it doesn't litter your global (or parent) scope.

Here's your directive:

```
.directive(
  'ngIncludeTemplate'
  () ->
    {
      templateUrl: (elem, attrs) -> attrs.ngIncludeTemplate
      restrict: 'A'
      scope: {
        'ngIncludeVariables': '&'
      }
      link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
        vars = scope.ngIncludeVariables()
        for key, value of vars
          scope[key] = value
    }
)
```

(It's in Coffeescript)

IMO, ng-include is a little bit strange. Having access to the global scope decreases its reusability.

Comment: Does this bind the data in even one direction?

Comment: I think so, unless `value` in `scope[key] = value` is an object. We should have done a deep copy there.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to watch the `ngIncludeVariables`?