# Add directives from directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, mvvm, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a directive that takes care of **adding more directives** to the element it is declared on.
For example, I want to build a directive that takes care of adding `datepicker`, `datepicker-language` and `ng-required="true"`.

If I try to add those attributes and then use `$compile` I obviously generate an infinite loop, so I am checking if I have already added the needed attributes:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('superDirective', function ($compile, $injector) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      link: function compile(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (element.attr('datepicker')) { // check
          return;
        }
        element.attr('datepicker', 'someValue');
        element.attr('datepicker-language', 'en');
        // some more
        $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    };
  });
```

Of course, if I don't `$compile` the element, the attributes will be set but the directive won't be bootstrapped.

Is this approach correct or am I doing it wrong? Is there a better way to achieve the same behavior?

**UDPATE**: given the fact that `$compile` is the only way to achieve this, is there a way to skip the first compilation pass (the element may contain several children)? Maybe by setting `terminal:true`?

**UPDATE 2**: I have tried putting the directive into a `select` element and, as expected, the compilation runs twice, which means there is twice the number of expected `option`s.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

In cases where you have multiple directives on a single DOM element and where the
order in which they’re applied matters, you can use the `priority` property to order their
application. Higher numbers run first. The default priority is 0 if you don’t specify one.

**EDIT**: after the discussion, here's the complete working solution. The key was to **remove the attribute**: `element.removeAttr("common-things");`, and also `element.removeAttr("data-common-things");` (in case users specify `data-common-things` in the html)

```js
angular.module('app')
  .directive('commonThings', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: false, 
      terminal: true, //this setting is important, see explanation below
      priority: 1000, //this setting is important, see explanation below
      compile: function compile(element, attrs) {
        element.attr('tooltip', '{{dt()}}');
        element.attr('tooltip-placement', 'bottom');
        element.removeAttr("common-things"); //remove the attribute to avoid indefinite loop
        element.removeAttr("data-common-things"); //also remove the same attribute with data- prefix in case users specify data-common-things in the html

        return {
          pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  },
          post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  
            $compile(iElement)(scope);
          }
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

Working plunker is available at: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q13bUt?p=preview

Or:

```js
angular.module('app')
  .directive('commonThings', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: false,
      terminal: true,
      priority: 1000,
      link: function link(scope,element, attrs) {
        element.attr('tooltip', '{{dt()}}');
        element.attr('tooltip-placement', 'bottom');
        element.removeAttr("common-things"); //remove the attribute to avoid indefinite loop
        element.removeAttr("data-common-things"); //also remove the same attribute with data- prefix in case users specify data-common-things in the html

        $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    };
  });
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tw1Pbt?p=preview)

**Explanation why we have to set `terminal: true` and `priority: 1000` (a high number):**

When the DOM is ready, angular walks the DOM to identify all registered directives and compile the directives one by one based on `priority` **if these directives are on the same element**. We set our custom directive's priority to a high number to ensure that it will be compiled **first** and with `terminal: true`, the other directives will be **skipped** after this directive is compiled.

When our custom directive is compiled, it will modify the element by adding directives and removing itself and use $compile service to **compile all the directives (including those that were skipped)**.

If we don't set `terminal:true` and `priority: 1000`, there is a chance that some directives are compiled **before** our custom directive. And when our custom directive uses $compile to compile the element => compile again the already compiled directives. This will cause unpredictable behavior especially if the directives compiled before our custom directive have already transformed the DOM.

For more information about priority and terminal, check out [How to understand the `terminal` of directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266840/how-to-understand-the-terminal-of-directive)

An example of a directive that also modifies the template is `ng-repeat` (priority = 1000), when `ng-repeat` is compiled, `ng-repeat` *make copies of the template element before other directives get applied*.

Thanks to @Izhaki's comment, here is the reference to `ngRepeat` source code: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js

Comment: I have put up a simple plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/JQfhqN?p=preview. As you can see, the DOM is edited, but the added directives are not instantiated, which means they're not compiled.

Comment: @frapontillo: sorry, you need to return a link function. http://jsfiddle.net/WZGUB/

Comment: It throws a stack overflow exception to me: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` as it goes on compiling forever.

Comment: @frapontillo: in your case, try adding `element.removeAttr("common-datepicker");` to avoid indefinite loop.

Comment: Compilation still runs twice: I have updated the plnkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/JQfhqN?p=preview) and simplified it by using just a `tooltip`. The `tooltip` is shown, but the `select` options are set twice.
The first run compiles the element without the new attributes, and adds the select options. The second run compiles the element with the newly added attributes, but adds those options again.

Comment: Ok, I've been able to sort it out, you have to set `replace: false`, `terminal: true`, `priority: 1000`; then set the desired attributes in the `compile` function and remove our directive attribute. Finally, in the `post` function returned by `compile`, call `$compile(element)(scope)`. The element will be regularly compiled without the custom directive but with the added attributes. What I was trying to achieve was not to remove the custom directive and handle all of this in one process: this can't be done, it seems. Please refer to the updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q13bUt?p=preview.

Comment: Note that if you need to use the attributes object parameter of the compile or link functions, know that the directive responsible for interpolating attribute values has priority 100, and your directive needs to have a lower priority than this, or else you will only get the string values of the attributes due to the directory being terminal. See (see [this github pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4649) and this [related issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4525))

Comment: What about support for `data-common-things`?  I'd expect to see `element.removeAttr("data-common-things");` in the `compile` as well.

Comment: what would be the case where you need to access the ngModel of the element? if you do a `require: 'ngModel'` it fails...

Comment: @pocesar: Why do you need something like this? The purpose of this directive is just to add directives. We should not have `require: 'ngModel'`.

Comment: @KhanhTO at the same time I'm adding directive, I want to push some formatters to the model, but it makes sense to create a subdirective for this instead

Comment: Great answer. Given the priority and terminal values, I assume it is impossible for such a directive to require controllers on the same element? e.g. `require: "abc"`. Accessing parent controllers is fine, e.g. `require: '^def'` but sibling controllers seem out of the question?

Comment: @KhanhTO "in the compile phase, ng-repeat make copies of the template element before other directives get applied."; not sure this is correct - if you look at the [code of ng-repeat](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js), it creates the clones in the (post) link function.

Comment: @Izhaki: yes, you're correct. I've removed the old solution completely and updated the answer

Comment: @KhanhTO I find it best to put $compile(iElement)(scope); in the pre link, because then you can also change ng-model and it is picked up (which is what I do in a crazy case I have).

Comment: @user2000095-tim: what do you mean by changing `ng-model` and it is picked up?

Comment: @KhanhTO if you change an attribute on your element (or indeed add children) then they need to be compiled before they are seen by angular. So you can change ng-model if you really need to by recompiling the element.

Comment: @user2000095-tim: It should work in this case, but I'm not sure if it has any differences. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297797/when-shall-we-use-prelink-of-directives-compile-function and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297208/post-link-vs-pre-link-in-angular-js-directives

Comment: It is important to know that if 'terminal' is set to true, not only the directives with lower priority on the same element will be skipped, but also the directives on the decedent elements will be skipped. This is why double-compiling in the children elements can be prevented.

Comment: as an alternative to removing the `common-things` attributes you could pass a maxPriority parameter to the compile command: `$compile(element, null, 1000)(scope);`

Comment: Quick note: `ng-repeat` has a priority of 1000, put a bigger number if you need to run before.

Comment: To avoid loop at compilation, have a look at ignoreDirective parameter of the $compile function: compile($compileNodes, transcludeFn, maxPriority, ignoreDirective, previousCompileContext) (maybe only available in latest angular version ?)

Comment: ng-model which is bind to select element is not updated when you change option. It's always on initial value. Is there any way to fix if? It's because of compiling element on which is ng-model binded, but I don't know how fix it.

Comment: @Error: please post a detailed question, I'm sure there will be answers

Answer (score 10):

You can actually handle all of this with just a simple template tag. See http://jsfiddle.net/m4ve9/ for an example. Note that I actually didn't need a compile or link property on the super-directive definition.

During the compilation process, Angular pulls in the template values before compiling, so you can attach any further directives there and Angular will take care of it for you.

If this is a super directive that needs to preserve the original internal content, you can use `transclude : true` and replace the inside with `<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>`

Hope that helps, let me know if anything is unclear

Alex

Comment: Thank you Alex, the problem to this approach is that I can't make any assumption on what the tag will be. In the example it was a datepicker, i.e. an `input` tag, but I'd like to make it work for any element, such as `div`s or `select`s.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I missed that. In that case I'd recommend sticking with a div and just making sure your other directives can work on that. It's not the cleanest of answers, but fits best within the Angular methodology. By the time the bootstrap process has begun compiling an HTML node, it's already collected all the directives on the node for compilation, so adding a new one there won't get noticed by the original bootstrap process. Depending on your needs, you may find wrapping everything in a div and working within that gives you more flexibility, but it also limits where you can put your element.

Comment: @frapontillo You can use a template as a function with `element` and `attrs` passed in. Took me ages to work that out, and I haven't seen it used anywhere - but it seems to work fine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20137542/1455709

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that moves the directives that need to be added dynamically, into the view and also adds some optional (basic) conditional-logic. This keeps the directive clean with no hard-coded logic.

The directive takes an array of objects, each object contains the name of the directive to be added and the value to pass to it (if any).

I was struggling to think of a use-case for a directive like this until I thought that it might be useful to add some conditional logic that only adds a directive based on some condition (though the answer below is still contrived). I added an optional `if` property that should contain a bool value, expression or function (e.g. defined in your controller) that determines if the directive should be added or not.

I'm also using `attrs.$attr.dynamicDirectives` to get the exact attribute declaration used to add the directive (e.g. `data-dynamic-directive`, `dynamic-directive`) without hard-coding string values to check for.

[<kbd>Plunker Demo</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/f28p1z?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
            $scope.dt = function() {
                return new Date();
            };
            $scope.selects = [1, 2, 3, 4];
            $scope.el = 2;

            // For use with our dynamic-directive
            $scope.selectIsRequired = true;
            $scope.addTooltip = function() {
                return true;
            };
        }
    ])
    .directive('dynamicDirectives', ['$compile',
        function($compile) {
            
             var addDirectiveToElement = function(scope, element, dir) {
                var propName;
                if (dir.if) {
                    propName = Object.keys(dir)[1];
                    var addDirective = scope.$eval(dir.if);
                    if (addDirective) {
                        element.attr(propName, dir[propName]);
                    }
                } else { // No condition, just add directive
                    propName = Object.keys(dir)[0];
                    element.attr(propName, dir[propName]);
                }
            };
            
            var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var directives = scope.$eval(attrs.dynamicDirectives);
        
                if (!directives || !angular.isArray(directives)) {
                    return $compile(element)(scope);
                }
               
                // Add all directives in the array
                angular.forEach(directives, function(dir){
                    addDirectiveToElement(scope, element, dir);
                });
                
                // Remove attribute used to add this directive
                element.removeAttr(attrs.$attr.dynamicDirectives);
                // Compile element to run other directives
                $compile(element)(scope);
            };
        
            return {
                priority: 1001, // Run before other directives e.g.  ng-repeat
                terminal: true, // Stop other directives running
                link: linker
            };
        }
    ]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div data-ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">

        <select data-ng-options="s for s in selects" data-ng-model="el" 
            data-dynamic-directives="[
                { 'if' : 'selectIsRequired', 'ng-required' : '{{selectIsRequired}}' },
                { 'tooltip-placement' : 'bottom' },
                { 'if' : 'addTooltip()', 'tooltip' : '{{ dt() }}' }
            ]">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Used in an other directive template. It's work just fine and save my time. Just thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to add my solution since the accepted one didn't quite work for me.

I needed to add a directive but also keep mine on the element.

In this example I am adding a simple ng-style directive to the element. To prevent infinite compile loops and allowing me to keep my directive I added a check to see if what I added was present before recompiling the element.

```js
angular.module('some.directive', [])
.directive('someDirective', ['$compile',function($compile){
    return {
        priority: 1001,
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$transclude' ,function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {

            // controller code here

        }],
        compile: function(element, attributes){
            var compile = false;

            //check to see if the target directive was already added
            if(!element.attr('ng-style')){
                //add the target directive
                element.attr('ng-style', "{'width':'200px'}");
                compile = true;
            }
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  },
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    if(compile){
                        $compile(iElement)(scope);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: It is worth noting that you cannot use this with transclude or a template, as the compiler attempts to re-apply them in the second round.

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the state in a attribute on the element itself, such as `superDirectiveStatus="true"`

For example:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('superDirective', function ($compile, $injector) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      link: function compile(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (element.attr('datepicker')) { // check
          return;
        }
        var status = element.attr('superDirectiveStatus');
        if( status !== "true" ){
             element.attr('datepicker', 'someValue');
             element.attr('datepicker-language', 'en');
             // some more
             element.attr('superDirectiveStatus','true');
             $compile(element)(scope);

        }

      }
    };
  });
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, the basic concept stays the same :). I am trying to figure out a way to skip the first compilation pass. I have updated the original question.

Comment: The double compilation breaks things in an awful way.

Answer (score 1):

There was a change from 1.3.x to 1.4.x.

In Angular 1.3.x this worked:

```
var dir: ng.IDirective = {
    restrict: "A",
    require: ["select", "ngModel"],
    compile: compile,
};

function compile(tElement: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, tAttrs, transclude) {
    tElement.append("<option value=''>--- Kein ---</option>");

    return function postLink(scope: DirectiveScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: ng.IAttributes) {
        attributes["ngOptions"] = "a.ID as a.Bezeichnung for a in akademischetitel";
        scope.akademischetitel = AkademischerTitel.query();
    }
}
```

Now in Angular 1.4.x we have to do this:

```
var dir: ng.IDirective = {
    restrict: "A",
    compile: compile,
    terminal: true,
    priority: 10,
};

function compile(tElement: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, tAttrs, transclude) {
    tElement.append("<option value=''>--- Kein ---</option>");
    tElement.removeAttr("tq-akademischer-titel-select");
    tElement.attr("ng-options", "a.ID as a.Bezeichnung for a in akademischetitel");

    return function postLink(scope: DirectiveScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: ng.IAttributes) {

        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.akademischetitel = AkademischerTitel.query();
    }
}
```

(From the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19228302/605586 from Khanh TO).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that could work in some cases is to create and $compile a wrapper and then append your original element to it.

Something like...

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr){
    var wrapper = angular.element('<div tooltip></div>');
    elem.before(wrapper);
    $compile(wrapper)(scope);
    wrapper.append(elem);
}
```

This solution has the advantage that it keeps things simple by not recompiling the original element.

This wouldn't work if any of the added directive's `require` any of the original element's directives or if the original element has absolute positioning.