# AngularJS dynamic form field validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to validate some form fields which are given to me from a backend endpoint...

So basically the `input` elements are dynamically created inside a `ng-repeat`.
Therefore, the `input` attributes are also dynamically added, such as the `type`, `name`, etc...

However because the `name` attribute is dynamically added, when I try to validate it, like this, for example:

```
myForm.elName.$valid
```

It doesn't return anything because at this point, it doesn't know what `elName` is.

I created a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/HB7LU/1889/

Any help or advice will be much appreciated!

FANX.

**EDIT:**
I've been referring to this AWESOME documentation:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.email

Comment: Please, develop. Why do you regret every seconds of angularJS?

Comment: This is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071413/dynamic-form-name-attribute-input-type-text-name-variable-name-in

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try my custom directive:

```
myApp.directive("dynamicName",function($compile){
  return {
      restrict:"A",
      terminal:true,
      priority:1000,
      link:function(scope,element,attrs){
          element.attr('name', scope.$eval(attrs.dynamicName));
          element.removeAttr("dynamic-name");
          $compile(element)(scope);
      }
   };
});
```

Use it:

```
<input dynamic-name="field.name"
       type="{{ field.type }}"
       placeholder="{{ field.name }}"
       ng-model="field.value"
       required>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YAZmz/2/)

**Explanation of the problem:**

By default, input elements using ngModelController (`ng-model`) call `FormController.$addControl` when they are linked to register itself and expose a property on the `FormController` with the **name property of the input** which is `{{ field.name }}` in this case. Therefore, even though the control is registered but you don't have exposed properties on `FormController` with named `email`, `firstName`, you only have `{{ field.name }}` referencing **the last input item**

**Explanation of the solution:**

In this solution, I created a custom directive to replace the `{{ field.name }}` with the correct name at runtime.

For more information why I have to use `terminal:true,` and `priority:1000`, check out this discussion: [Add directives from directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs/19228302#19228302)

Comment: A isolated scope can be used instead of scope.$eval: `scope: { dynamicName: '=' }` in the directive configuration then simply `scope.dynamicName` inside `link`.

Comment: @Hugo Wood: I don't think we need isolate scope here. The purpose of this directive is to `modify the current element` based on `current scope`. Using current scope is more appropriate IMO.

Comment: can I loop through error messages dynamically ? they are hardcoded in the demo

Comment: @sisimh: yes, just use javascript bracket notation: `{{ myForm[formFields[0].name].$valid }}`: http://jsfiddle.net/3qu3tu6f/

Comment: thank you for ur reply @KhanhTO , actually i am thinking of returning the validation error from the directive it self , in that case how can I concat form name with the error fields like what u did except that i dont have "myForm"  hardcoded

Comment: @sisimh: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. In that case, you can also apply javascript bracket notation like: `MyCtrl[myForm]`