# Angularjs: form validation and input directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I created a directive in an AngularJS app which produces styled input in my application. It looks like this:

```
AC.directive('formInput',function ($compile) {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope:{},
        templateUrl: '/views/partials/form/input.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            scope.opts = attrs;

            if(attrs.ngModel){
                element.find('input').attr('ng-model', attrs.ngModel);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope.$parent);
            }

            if(!attrs.type){
                scope.opts.type = 'text';
            }
        }
    };
  }
)
```

And the template for it is:

```
<label class="acxm-textfield {{opts.cssclass}}">
  <span ng-bind="opts.labeltext"></span>
  <input type="{{opts.type}}" name="{{opts.inputname}}" value="{{opts.inputvalue}}" placeholder="{{opts.placeholder}}" ng-maxlength="{{opts.maxLength}}"/>
</label>
```

The call is simple:

```
<form-input ng-model="UserProfile.FirstName" max-length="50" labeltext="{{'GENERAL.name' | translate}}" cssclass="acxm-p-horizontal" inputname="name" inputvalue="{{UserProfile.FirstName}}"></form-input>
```

I wanted to create validation for this field and I added an error information:

```
<span ng-show="showError(userInfoForm.name,'email')">
                    You must enter a valid email
</span>
```

And showError is:

```
$scope.showError = function(ngModelController, error) {

    return ngModelController.$error[error];
};
```

Basically, it is copied from the book "Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS". I have a problem because when I log my form, which name is `userInfoForm`, in console I got `{{opts.inputname}}` instead of name property which value here should be "name". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: take a look at my answer to a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455695/angularjs-dynamic-form-field-validation/21457121#21457121

Comment: Declare the directive as in the link I posted and replace `name="{{opts.inputname}}"` with `dynamic-name="opts.inputname"`

Comment: Khanh yes I could create a directive but since my input is already a directive I added only: element.find('input').attr('name', scope.opts.inputname); and it adds a name attr but I cannot stil make work my validation :/ in showError the ngModelController is still undefined when I try to access my field... here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/xKktbdw1dP5elWKnmQMC?p=preview

Comment: Yes I think your remarks are good... Hmmm but how to make it work :)

Comment: I found out that my solution works, just forgot to put `required` to my input field. Silly me. I posted as an answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try my `dynamic-name` directive here: [AngularJS dynamic form field validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455695/angularjs-dynamic-form-field-validation/21457121#21457121)

Replace `name="{{opts.inputname}}"` with `dynamic-name="opts.inputname"`

I also simplified your code for demonstration:

```
app.directive("dynamicName", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    terminal: true,
    priority: 1000,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var name = scope.$eval(attrs.dynamicName);
      if (name) {
        element.attr('name', name);
        element.removeAttr("dynamic-name");
        $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    }
  };
});

app.directive('formInput', function($compile) {
  return {
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'formInput.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.opts = attrs;


      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
  }
});
```

Form Input template:

```
<label class="acxm-textfield {{opts.cssclass}}">
  <span ng-bind="opts.labeltext"></span>
  <input type="{{opts.type}}" dynamic-name="opts.inputname" ng-model="opts.inputvalue"
  placeholder="{{opts.placeholder}}" 
  ng-maxlength="{{opts.maxLength}}" required/> //use dynamic-name directive to bind dynamic names.
</label>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6v1QAMEzrixu5FfkAxGD?p=preview) (try clearing the text to see the validation, I used required validation for quick demonstration, you could change the code to email validation). The key is using the `dynamic-name` directive.

Comment: Khanh thanks for help your example works YOU ROCK! :) I think that the main problem was that my directive used value and ng-model :) because only diff is that your directive doesn't use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take on form / name validation directives
[stacklink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071413/dynamic-form-name-attribute-input-type-text-name-variable-name-in)

```
<form name="myFormName">
  <nested directives of many levels>
  ex: <input ng-repeat=(index, variable) in variables" type="text"
             my-name="{{ variable.name + '/' + 'myFormName' }}"
             ng-model="variable.name" required />
  ex: <select ng-model="variable.name" ng-options="label in label in {{ variable.options }}"
             my-name="{{ variable.name + '/' + 'myFormName' }}"
      </select>
</form
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

```
app.directive('rsName', function(){

  var rsNameError = "rsName directive error: "

  return {
    restrict:'A', // Declares an Attributes Directive.
    require: 'ngModel', // ngModelController.

    link: function( scope, elem, attrs, ngModel ){
      if( !ngModel ){ return } // no ngModel exists for this element

      // check rsName input for proper formatting ex. something/something
      checkInputFormat(attrs);

      var inputName = attrs.rsName.match('^\\w+').pop(); // match upto '/'
      assignInputNameToInputModel(inputName, ngModel);

      var formName = attrs.rsName.match('\\w+$').pop(); // match after '/'
      findForm(formName, ngModel, scope);
    } // end link
  } // end return

  function checkInputFormat(attrs){
    if( !/\w\/\w/.test(attrs.rsName )){
      throw rsNameError + "Formatting should be \"inputName/formName\" but is " + attrs.rsName
    }
  }

  function assignInputNameToInputModel(inputName, ngModel){
    ngModel.$name = inputName
  }

  function addInputNameToForm(formName, ngModel, scope){
    scope[formName][ngModel.$name] = ngModel; return
  }

  function findForm(formName, ngModel, scope){
    if( !scope ){ // ran out of scope before finding scope[formName]
      throw rsNameError + "<Form> element named " + formName + " could not be found."
    }

    if( formName in scope){ // found scope[formName]
      addInputNameToForm(formName, ngModel, scope)
      return
    }
    findForm(formName, ngModel, scope.$parent) // recursively search through $parent scopes
  }
});
```