# How to use dynamic input name inside of directive

Tags: forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to implement a directive that implements a a complex input type for a form. To achieve this, the ng-model (for binding the value) and name (for registering to the form for validating) have to be set accordingly.
While ng-model works as it should, I can't find a way to set the name dynamically.

[see Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bE7wPyplFVgoZ9X0kbsb)

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div class="morestuff"><input name="{{name}}" ng-model="ngModel"></div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      name: '=',
      ngModel: '='
    }
  };
```

When I use it inside my form like

```
<form name="myform">
  <input type="text" ng-model="value1" name="name1">
  <my-directive name="name2" ng-model="value2"></my-directive>
</form>
```

it results in three entries to myform:

```
{
  "name1": {},
  "{{name}}": {},
  "name2": {}
}
```

So my questions:

1. How could I implement the desired behaviour?
2. Why is there an entry from the my-directive element? Shouldn't that have been removed due to replace: true?

Comment: take a look at my answer to this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455695/angularjs-dynamic-form-field-validation/21457121#21457121

Comment: This worked fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/74E3L/  can you fork this to show what is wrong?  (Maybe how you outputted your entries).

Comment: @nix: sorry, I forgotr the link to my plunker, just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo, you should use ng-attr-name

Here is an updated version:

http://jsfiddle.net/L99az/1/

For your template:

```
 <div class="morestuff">
      <input type="text" data-ng-attr-name="{{name}}" ng-model="ngModel"/>
      {{name}}
 </div>
```

You could also try to play with the "terminal" property of the directive to clear the output of your form.

e.g:

http://plnkr.co/edit/z9Jf30KSCOkTM6vEHZwv?p=preview

Comment: This seems to work only partially on input validation options like "min": While the arrows in the input field seem to know the min=100, angular validatioon doesn't seem to catch up: http://plnkr.co/edit/LbC6tVN6IrBql909JzMB?p=preview