# Why can't my filtered list of radio buttons validate in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I am working on a multi-step form in Angular. One of the steps on the form is to pick a procedure type, which could become a very long list. I decided to add basic search functionality to narrow down the list.

The list of procedure types is output into a table with `ng-repeat` and a filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="procedure in procedureTypes
               | filter: query
               | orderBy:orderProp
               as filteredProcedureTypes">
  <td >
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="procedureType"
      id="procedureFormProcedureType"
      ng-model="newProcedure.procedureType"
      value="{{procedure.id}}"
      required>
  </td>
  <td>{{procedure.ncdManualId}}</td>
  <td>{{procedure.name}}</td>
  <td>{{procedure.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Check input in controller:

```
if ($scope.newProcedureForm.procedureType.$invalid){
      return false;
    }
```

The validation works when checking against unfiltered list and when query does not remove any of the items. When the query removes 1 or more items, I get

**TypeError: Cannot read property '$invalid' of undefined**

`newProcedure` and `newProcedureForm` show up as objects in console, but I can't figure out why `newProcedureForm.procedureType` becomes undefined after query alters the list of radio buttons.

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: works for me...http://plnkr.co/edit/ioT5SiSFFeE9pyXnFm5v?p=info

Comment: @Pavan Thanks for creating the demo. I edited it to replicate the problem. [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/AxVSfzmfkY4AUvBYDmwz) 

To see the problem click the radio for 32, search 22, click the radio for 22 and then submit.

Comment: Looks like your problem is similar to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455695/angularjs-dynamic-form-field-validation/21457121#21457121