# How can I create a directive that adds ng-class and ng-disabled on the target element based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
app.directive "ngDisableOnVar", ($compile) ->
  restrict: "A"
  terminal: true
  priority: 1000
  replace:false
  scope: {}
  compile: compile = (element, attrs) ->
    cattr = attrs["ngDisableOnVar"]
    element.attr("ng-class", "{'disabled': !#{cattr}}")
    element.attr("ng-disabled", "!#{cattr}")
    element.removeAttr("ng-disable-on-var")
    pre: preLink = (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) ->

    post: postLink = (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) ->
      $compile(iElement)(scope)
```

I tried to base the code on the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs). Basically, I'd like to have the following:

```
<input ngDisableOnVar="someScopeVariable>
```

And have it replaced with the following:

```
<input ng-class="{'disabled': !someScopeVariable}" ng-disabled="!someScopeVariable">
```

Something is wrong, cause even though I have them applied to my element, they're always disabled, even though the scope variable evaluates to true. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: 
I created a plunker, where the first 2 buttons are created with ng-class and ng-disabled, and the other 2 buttons, should have the same things applied on them through the use of the directive.

Here is the plunker version with shared scope: http://plnkr.co/edit/TebCQL20ubh5AgJ6nMIl?p=preview

And here's the one without the shared scope:http://plnkr.co/edit/CPm55MrHA8z6Bx4GbxoN?p=preview

The problem is, the one without the shared scope does not update. How can I make them update, and have the conditions depend on the variables passed as arguments?

EDIT #2:
I'm starting to believe that the scope sharing is the correct way these 2 buttons should act, short of creating a new directive that encapsulates both buttons within it. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: The problem is the scope value is not set during the compile phase.

Comment: Is there a way to adjust it?

Comment: you could compile everything during the link phase using `$compile(template)(scope);`

Comment: just submitted an answer/example

Comment: I added 1 more solution that IMO is the best to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with your EDIT #2 because **they are related**. If we create them as separate elements, we need to somehow pass the related element to each one => When we click on 1 button, we update itself and also the related element.

Here I modified your first approach to make it work: http://plnkr.co/edit/KgYIlATiw9xzTEZt9Jv1?p=preview

In this example, I have to pass the related element to each directive so that when we click we can update itself and the related element:

```
related-element="btnForward"
```

I did some modifications in the directive:

```
scope: {
      reactOn: "=", //use property binding instead of function binding
      relatedElement:"@" 
    },
link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
      scope.toggle = function(){
        scope.reactOn = !scope.reactOn;//toggle current element
        var relatedScope = $("#"+scope.relatedElement).scope();//get related element's scope and toggle it
        relatedScope.reactOn = !relatedScope.reactOn;
      }
      //var cattr = attrs.ngDisableReactOn;
      element.attr("ng-class", "{'disabled': !reactOn}"); //Use reactOn instead as this is the property of current scope
      element.attr("ng-disabled", "!reactOn");
      element.attr("ng-click", "toggle()"); 
      element.removeAttr("ng-disable-react-on");
      $compile(element)(scope);
    }
```

We don't need to make things complex. Just create a normal directive to wrap 2 buttons.

```
myApp.directive("ngDisableReactOn", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    templateUrl:"ngDisableReactOn.html",
    scope: {
      can_go_back: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
      scope.goBack = function(){
          scope.can_go_back = false;
      }

      scope.goFwd = function(){
          scope.can_go_back = true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<input type="button" value="go back" ng-click="goBack()"  ng-class="{'disabled': !can_go_back}" ng-disabled="!can_go_back">
<input type="button" value="go fwd"  ng-click="goFwd()"   ng-class="{'disabled': can_go_back}" ng-disabled="can_go_back">
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/G1EvovL4LP8g8gh6FyOG?p=preview)

Another solution is to create a parent directive as a container. This is the solution I like the most. With this approach, you can freely change the inner content of the directive like adding more buttons, more text,....(**DON'T NEED TO HARDCODE THE TEMPLATE**) The parent directive works as a manager to ensure there is only 1 active child at a time:

```
myApp.directive("ngDisableReactOnContainer", function() { //Container directive to manage all child directives
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,//Use transclusion to move inner content to the template
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    controller: function() {
      var children = []; 
      this.selectChild = function(activeChild) { //ensure that only 1 child is active at a time
        activeChild.active = true;
        angular.forEach(children, function(child) {
          if (child != activeChild) {
            child.active = false;
          }
        });
      }

      this.addChild = function(child) {
        children.push(child);
      }
    }
  };
});

myApp.directive("ngDisableReactOn", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",

    scope:{
      active:"@"
    },

    require: '^?ngDisableReactOnContainer',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

      scope.active = scope.active === 'true';

      controller.addChild(scope);//register itself with the container

      scope.select = function(){//When this element is clicked, inform the container to toggle all children accordingly.
         controller.selectChild(scope);
      }

      //Add ng-class and ng-disabled based on your requirement.
      element.attr("ng-class", "{'disabled': active}"); //Use active instead as this is the property of current scope
      element.attr("ng-disabled", "active");
      element.attr("ng-click", "select()"); 
      element.removeAttr("ng-disable-react-on");
      $compile(element)(scope);
    }
  }
});
```

Using these directives would be simple:

```
<div ng-disable-react-on-container>
    <input ng-disable-react-on type="button" value="button 1" active="true" >
    <input ng-disable-react-on type="button" value="button 2" >
    <input ng-disable-react-on type="button" value="button 3" >
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/DKF0KzjsR2KnupwXDpbZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very ugly way to demonstrate how to compile the template during the link function. It is ugly because I didn't address any binding on the scope variable. You might want to isolate the scope or setup two-way binding but this should give you the gist of how to access the scope for compiling purposes.

```
app.directive('foo', function($compile) {
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    var html;
    if (scope.testVar)
      html = '<input ng-class="{\'disabled\': !someScopeVariable}" ng-disabled="!someScopeVariable" />';
    else
      html = '<input />';
    var htmlEl = angular.element(html),
      compiledEl = $compile(htmlEl)(scope);
    elem.replaceWith(compiledEl);
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/xBS4ZMXVwqv8CwWvwTu5?p=preview

Comment: I don't want to critizise your answer - I don't know a better one. But when I see such things (in my own AngularJS-code as well), I have a really bad feeling. My experience with such constructions is that it will become a maintenance and bugfix nightmare. Better be little more verbously and avoid such things. **Just my opinion...**

Comment: Completely understand your point. That is why I said it was "very ugly". I was just trying to demonstrate how to use `$compile` without having to abstract everything out.

Answer (score 1):

You can get same effect with another similar approach. Plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/g56cmN2C7STPYFhiawOc?p=preview)

Instead of `$compile` in link function you can use `template` in your directive and `ng-disabled` with a variable in scope that is bind to parent scope variable via isolated scope.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to remove the `!` before the var name?

```
<input ng-class="{'disabled': someScopeVariable}" ng-disabled="someScopeVariable">
```

Comment: But I don't understand how that would make a difference. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In the first time you use someScoepvariable and after !someScopeVariable. But perhaps i didn't understand the problem.