# extend angular-carousel directive (template + ng-show binding)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to extend 'rnCarouselControls' directive of revolunet/angular-carousel. I want to extend it with hiding logic (hide arrows) when there is no focus on image.
I've read 'Understanding Directives' article and seems that stacking technique could help but can't get it working. 
Tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/19228302/1407492 this solution with

```
app.directive('rnCarouselControls', function ($compile) {
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          replace: true,
          priority: 1000,
          terminal:true,
          compile: function compile(element, attrs) {
              element.removeAttr("rn-carousel-controls");
              element.attr('ng-show', '$parent.activecontrols');
              return {
                  pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { },
                  post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                      $compile(iElement)(scope);

                  }
              };
          }
      };
  })
```

if `terminal=true` then second directive doesn't trigger. from accepted answer:

> When our custom directive is compiled, it will modify the element by
>   adding directives and removing itself and use $compile service to
>   compile all the directives (including those that were skipped).

not true for this directive.

Comment: I think you just may override default css for carousel hiding the  .carousel-control{visibility:hidden;}. And then show it when 'carousel:focus .carousel-control{visibility:visible;} '

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right. it works! (I should learn css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I commented the solution is to make it by only css:

```
.carousel-control{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

And then show it when

```
carousel:focus .carousel-control{
  visibility:visible;
}
```