# AngularJS - ngRepeat is applied double times when $compile the element's attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want this

```
$scope.name = 'Angular';
$scope.list = ['foo: {{name}}', 'bar: {{name}}'];

<div ng-repeat="template in list" compile="template"></div>
```

to be

```
<div real="foo: Angular"></div>
<div real="bar: Angular"></div>
```

So i use $compile:

```
$compileProvider.directive('compile', function ($compile) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
            function (scope) {
                return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
            },
            function (value) {
                //element.html(value);
                //$compile(element.contents())(scope);

                element.attr("real", value);
                element.removeAttr("compile");
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
        );
    };
})
```

but, it output:

```
<div real="foo: Angular"></div>
<div real="foo: Angular"></div>
<div real="bar: Angular"></div>
<div real="bar: Angular"></div>
```

so what's the problem ?

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/OdnriGpd7eMBtfp2u1b2?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="template in list">
    <div compile="template"></div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/fKMlNqNnjz7ID089cIpS?p=preview)

**Explanation**:

When you put your directive on the same element with `ng-repeat` and call `$compile(element)(scope);`, your element is **recompiled** *including the ng-repeat*, causing the `ng-repeat` to run one more time. When I also remove the ng-repeat in the directive, it works:

```
  element.attr("real", value);
  element.removeAttr("compile");
  element.removeAttr("ng-repeat");
  $compile(element)(scope);
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/LfmlyMitH14Vb3WBXQwx?p=preview)

This solution is not recommended because we hard-code the `element.removeAttr("ng-repeat");`

Remember to also apply `priority:1500` and `terminal:true` to the directive to avoid compiling again after angular has compiled the element:

```
$compileProvider.directive('compile', function($compile) {
    return {
      priority:1500,
      terminal:true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
          function(scope) {
            return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
          },
          function(value) {
            //element.html(value);
            //$compile(element.contents())(scope);

            element.attr("real", value);
            element.removeAttr("compile");
            $compile(element)(scope);
          }
        );
      }
    };
  });
```

For more information about these 2 settings. Check out [Add directives from directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs/19228302#19228302)

Comment: Thanks!! i have another problem that if the `<div compile="template">` has a child element with ngClick, ngClick event are firing twice?! [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/pYjBiykvTTNvzKKulHrI?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the pre link function : http://plnkr.co/edit/VIOAX1akTPF68DYxZQcQ

```
angular.module('demo', [], function($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.directive('compile', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict:'A',
      compile: function(celement, cattrs) {
        return{
          pre: function(scope,element,attrs){
            var attribute = scope[attrs.compile];
            element.attr('real',attribute);
            element.removeAttr('compile');
            $compile(element)(scope);
          },
          post: function(scope,ielmt,iattrs){

          }
        }
      }
    };
  })
});

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Angular';
  $scope.list = ['foo: {{name}}', 'bar: {{name}}'];
}
```