# AngularJS : $compile issue with nested "parent dependent" directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an issue while developing my Angular library : angular-coq.

I'm trying to provide these features :

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <form coq-model="team1">
        <!-- Inputs will be automatically added to form (wrapped in <p>) -->
    </form>
</div>
```

With `myController` that expose in scope `team1`, a custom class with 2 attributes : `id`, `name`.

The `CoqModel` directive will append to element a `<input coq-model-attribute="...">` for each attribute.

`CoqModelAttribute` directive need a `CoqModel` as parent to have reference of the current model (here `team1`) and will compile as follow:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <form coq-model="team1">
        <input type="<attribute_name>" ng-model="team1.<attribute_name>" coq-model-attribute="<attribute_name>"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

[Here is the implementation of CoqModel directive](https://github.com/squareteam/angular-coq/blob/e009b9b0d29dc7f12de47653874890943ec0d16b/lib/directives/coq-model.js) and [here is the implementation of CoqModelAttribute directive](https://github.com/squareteam/angular-coq/blob/e009b9b0d29dc7f12de47653874890943ec0d16b/lib/directives/coq-model-attribute.js) ( too large to paste here )

You will see that I "double-$compile" `CoqModel` directive.
If I don't do this, the generated inputs `ng-model` will not be binded..

So everything works fine expect that the "double-$compile" cause some issues with `ng-click`.

In this case :

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <form coq-model="team1">
        <input coq-model-attribute="name"/>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="click me" ng-click="team1.update()" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Clicking on "click me" will call the method `team1.update` 2 times..

I've tried a lot of different refactoring, all failed to solve this issue...
If one of you is an angular expert, please show me how to fix this :)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What are you doing that you need to manually call `$compile` in the first place? It looks like most of the logic in your pre `link` function generates markup which shouldn't be done here. You should be using a template for your directive and using that for creating your markup. Even if you really need to generate markup, it should be done inside of your directive's `compile` function, not `link`. Check out this explanation of ngRepeat for example: http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/05/13/understanding-angularjs-directives-part1-ng-repeat-and-compile/

Comment: Hi @ju 
Thanks for your fast reply.
I cannot generate the markup in the compile function cause I need to $parse attributes value to know how many nodes to create.
And $parse need scope to evaluate values... You see the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126224/angularjs-ngrepeat-is-applied-double-times-when-compile-the-elements-attribu) to a similar issue on Stack Overflow, the important bit being:

> When you put your directive on the same element with ng-repeat and call $compile(element)(scope);, your element is recompiled including the ng-repeat, causing the ng-repeat to run one more time.

Perhaps during the second $compile, your button element is recompiled including the ng-click, causing the ng-click to run twice.

This hard-coded solution might work. Fill in the (selectorForYourButton) with a selector for the problem button and include this snippit right above the second $compile.

```
(selectorForYourButton).removeAttr("ng-click");
```

This may just remove the functionality of the ng-click altogether, though! If so, add the ng-click attribute back after the second $compile.

Or perhaps try replacing your `priority:101` in `coqModelAttribute` directive with

```
  priority:1500,
  terminal:true,
```

to avoid compiling again after angular has compiled the element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !
The first solution seems to me to be a hack and I'm searching for a real solution for my Angular problem.

The second one, more logical still not explain why do I need to double-compile my generated markup.
I think that I'm missing something in the compile/link directive mechanism...

I keep your second solution for know as a fix but I'm still searching a strong implementation for my `coq-model` directive