# Angularjs dynamic directive inside ngrepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Look at example:

```
$scope.fields = [{
    name: 'Email',
    dir : "abc"
}, {
    name: 'List',
   dir : "ddd"
}];

app.directive('abc', function () {});
app.directive('ddd', function () {});

<table class="table table-hover">
        <tr ng-repeat="p in fields">
          <input {{p.dir}} ngmodel="p" />
        </tr>
    </table>
```

How can I write code, that `p.dir` will dynamically convert to a `directive` ?

My example: hhttp://jsbin.com/vejib/1/edit

Comment: Do you really need a directive for this? Can you just change to `<td>dddd: {{p.name}}</td><td>ddd: {{p.age}}</td>`?

Comment: @RuslanIsmagilov It's not about visual. Eash directive has it's own business logic. I'd like to dynamically build forms with custom business logic.

Comment: I think I have had similar porblems you need to set the directive scope to isolate. check the docs http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this directive:

```
app.directive('dynamicDirective',function($compile){
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: false, 
      terminal: true, 
      priority: 1000, 
      link:function(scope,element,attrs){

        element.attr(scope.$eval(attrs.dynamicDirective),"");//add dynamic directive

        element.removeAttr("dynamic-directive"); //remove the attribute to avoid indefinite loop
        element.removeAttr("data-dynamic-directive");

        $compile(element)(scope);
      }
  };
});
```

Use it:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
   <tr ng-repeat="p in people">
      <td dynamic-directive="p.dir" blah="p"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ET3LZhXBRjwIsbKVIwxm?p=preview)

For more information on how this directive works and why we have to add **terminal:true** and **priority: 1000**. Check out [Add directives from directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs/19228302#19228302)

Comment: Thank you. I thought angular has something like that build-in. apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

You could put this:

```
<input {{p.dir}} ngmodel="p" />
```

also in a directive. You could construct this HTML string in JavaScript and attach it to the DOM. And you would also need to compile the resulting element using the $compile service, so that the dynamic directives will be compiled.

Some dummy sample code (not tested, but should look something like this):

```
app.directive('dynamicInput', function($compile){
return {
    link: function(scope, element){
        var htmlString = '<input ' + scope.field.dir + ' ng-model="p"/>';
        element.replaceWith(htmlString);
        $compile(angular.element(element))(scope);
    }
}
```

});

More info [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile).