# ngRepeat on custom directive tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I have a list of custom directives which are different widgets on my dashboard. The directives are defined as follows:

```
angular.module('core').directive('graphCardWidget', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            target: '=target'
        },
        templateUrl: 'modules/core/widgets/graph-card.client.widget.html'
    };
});

angular.module('core').directive('pieChartWidget', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            target: '=target'
        },
        templateUrl: 'modules/core/widgets/pie-chart.client.widget.html'
    };
});
```

In my controller, I have a list of widgets to be displayed. The list is as follows:

```
$scope.dashboardWidgets = [
        {
            directive : 'graph-card-widget',
            target : 'widgets.dashboards.activeDevicesCard'
        },
        {
            directive : 'graph-card-widget',
            target : 'widgets.dashboards.activeSessionsCard'
        },
        {
            directive : 'pie-chart-widget',
            target : 'widgets.dashboards.devices'
        },
        {
            directive : 'pie-chart-widget',
            target : 'widgets.dashboards.sessions'
        }
    ];
```

Now in my view, I use `ng-repeat` to iterate this array and display the items. Here is the code of my view:

```
<div layout="row" layout-wrap layout-align="center" layout-xs="column" ng-drop="true">
    <div ng-repeat='widget in dashboardWidgets'>
        <{{widget.directive}} ng-drag="true" flex='45' target='{{widget.target}}'>
        </{{widget.directive}}>
        <span flex='5'></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the browser renders this as text. Here is what I get in my DOM:

```
<div layout="row" layout-wrap="" layout-align="center" layout-xs="column" ng-drop="true" class="layout-wrap layout-xs-column layout-align-center-stretch layout-row">
    <div ng-repeat="widget in dashboardWidgets" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
        “<graph-card-widget ng-drag="true" flex='45' target='widgets.dashboards.activeDevicesCard’>”
        <span flex="5" class="flex-5"></span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="widget in dashboardWidgets" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
        “<graph-card-widget ng-drag="true" flex='45' target='widgets.dashboards.activeSessionsCard’>”
        <span flex="5" class="flex-5"></span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="widget in dashboardWidgets" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
        “<pie-chart-widget ng-drag="true" flex='45' target='widgets.dashboards.devices’>”
        <span flex="5" class="flex-5"></span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="widget in dashboardWidgets" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
        “<pie-chart-widget ng-drag="true" flex='45' target='widgets.dashboards.sessions’>”
        <span flex="5" class="flex-5"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So what can I do to make the directive rendered as a tag and not plain text?

I saw a couple of questions similar to these such as, [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264534/dynamically-adding-directives-in-ng-repeat), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600710/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-custom-element-inside-a-table-is-rendering-strangely) but they all are adding the dynamic directives in standard HTML tags. What I need is a dynamic tag.

**Update:**

After following @cnexans answer, I got it working partially. The widget is drawn but the `target` attribute is not evaluated which leads to a blank widget.
Here's the plunkr with the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/BGN6C4LAHguWthU4fGy0?p=preview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamically adding directives in ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264534/dynamically-adding-directives-in-ng-repeat)

Comment: take a look at this - could be a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130430/angularjs-dynamic-directive-inside-ngrepeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-if inside ng-for in order to switch the name "directive" within each iteration to show one or another directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in dashboardWidgets">
    <div ng-if="data.directive == 'graph-card-widget'">
        <graph-card-widget ng-drag="true" flex='45' target=data.target>
        </graph-card-widget>
        <span flex='5'></span>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="data.directive == 'pie-chart-widget'">
        <pie-chart-widget ng-drag="true" flex='45' target=data.target>
        </pie-chart-widget>
        <span flex='5'></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can create a container directive to take care of this logic too, so you can share this functionality to other pages if needed.

```
<widgets-container widgets-list=data></widgets-container>
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBzEpe?editors=1010#0

**Edit:**

Checking the example you gave, you need to pass a Widget object to the directive, and you are passing a string. Here is a working example forked from the plunkr given

https://plnkr.co/edit/3Oxxmp?p=preview

It has a function namespaceToObject which transform the string into the desired object from $scope.

Comment: This approach fails with the error `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{data.target}}] starting at [{data.target}}].` And if I remove the `{{ }}` around `data.target`, it does not render the widget layout.

Comment: @Prerak Sola I apologize, a working example has been added to the answer

Comment: I am not sure why, but it still doesn't work for me. The `target` attribute is always evaluated to `data.target` and not value from the array. Here's the plunkr with the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/BGN6C4LAHguWthU4fGy0?p=preview The first two are widgets without using `ng-repeat` and the next two are generated by using `ng-repeat`.

Comment: It is because you are passing a string, and you want to pass an object from $scope. Try transforming the string to the desired object *edited the answer with the working plunkr

Comment: Yes it works now. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

don't know whether this will match your requirement. but i did some modification to your array.

I did this using `ng-bind-html` and when your are binding custom element like directive you need to compile it again. for that i create(actually borrow) this directive.

```
.directive('compileTemplate', function($compile, $parse){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
            function getStringValue() { return (parsed(scope) || '').toString(); }

            //Recompile if the template changes
            scope.$watch(getStringValue, function() {
                $compile(element, null, -9999)(scope);  //The -9999 makes it skip directives so that we do not recompile ourselves
            });
        }         
    }
});
```

I changed the `ng-repeat` like this

```
 <div ng-repeat='widget in dashboardWidgets' compile-template ng-bind-html="trust(widget.directive)">

        <span flex='5'></span>
 </div>
```

trust function will return trusted html

```
 $scope.trust = function(someHTML){ 
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(someHTML); 
 }
```

modify the array like this

```
$scope.dashboardWidgets = [
    {
        directive : '<graph-card-widget ng-drag="true" flex="45" target="widget.target"></ graph-card-widget>',
        target : 'widgets.dashboards.activeDevicesCard'
    },
    {
        directive : '<graph-card-widget ng-drag="true" flex="45" target="widget.target"></ graph-card-widget>',
        target : 'widgets.dashboards.activeSessionsCard'
    },
    {
        directive : '<pie-chart-widget ng-drag="true" flex="45" target="widget.target"></ pie-chart-widget>',
        target : 'widgets.dashboards.devices'
    },
    {
        directive : '<pie-chart-widget ng-drag="true" flex="45" target="widget.target"></ pie-chart-widget>',
        target : 'widgets.dashboards.sessions'
    }
];
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8lGXewA0TymgUlHZ1ehA?p=preview)

Comment: I tried to integrate it with my app, but it doesn't work. It literally prints the directive values. Here's the plunker with the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/UNzMfWpe9yAqrQKngqVv The first two widgets are generated via regular html markup and the second two are the one using `ngRepeat`.

Comment: @Prerak Sola i modify the `$scope.dashboardWidgets` array. check the updated array