# Adding ng-show from a directive without directly compiling or using templates

Tags: angularjs

Given HTML in the form of

`<p ng-repeat="item in items" my-directive="item">{{item.Description}}</p>`

I would like to dynamically add `ng-show` from within `my-directive`. It seems it is not as easy as perhaps it could be. If `my-directive` was an element instead of an attribute it could simply be done through a template, but alas the same support does not exist for attributes.

My first attempt used the `$compile` service as described at [Add directives from directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs). However, that approach relies on the directive being a higher priority than any other, and is therefore applied before the `ng-repeat`.

My current approach is to manually copy the source for `ng-show`:

```
.directive('myDirective', ['$animate', function ($animate) {
    function toBoolean(value) {
        if (typeof value === 'function') {
            value = true;
        } else if (value && value.length !== 0) {
            var v = angular.lowercase("" + value);
            value = !(v == 'f' || v == '0' || v == 'false' || v == 'no' || v == 'n' || v == '[]');
        } else {
            value = false;
        }
        return value;
    }

    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("myWatchExpression",
                function(isActive) {
                    $animate[toBoolean(isActive) ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass'](elem, 'ng-hide');
                }
            );
        }
    };
}])
```

However, that's obviously not a good long-term solution as it requires updating the custom directive whenever angular changes internally.

Is there any way to perhaps request a directive as an injectable and apply it to the element (without disrupting higher priority directives such as `ng-repeat`)?

**Edit to give context**

The directive I'm trying to create is for tabbed items. Ideally the markup looks like:

```
<tab-container>
    <button ng-repeat="tab in tabs" tab-button="{{tab.id}}">{{tab.name}}</button>
    <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" tab-view="{{tab.id}}"><ng-include src="{{tab.template}}"/></div>
</tab-container>
```

Thus I would like `ng-click` and `ng-class` directives on a `tab-button`, and `ng-show` on a `tab-view`.

Comment: I don't think  you need to do what you are doing.  Why can't you always just add the `ng-show` directive and control it being true/false using the same logic.  Or use a filter on the ng-repeat so that it's not even shown.  I couldn't tell exactly when you would want to dynamically add ng-show and what value it would have, but if you tell us how you wanted it to work, then we can suggest an alternative

Comment: @JoseM I have edited the question to give context

Comment: Like Jose said, it sounds more like you should have `ngShow` on each element and control the value if its expression.

Comment: Sure, I could - but I'm creating an abstraction here. I get the feeling that directives in Angular v1 are fundamentally not composable, which is a shame - I hope they get it right in v2

Comment: @AlexG: I don't really understand what you mean by "composable". But wanting to use directives (i.e. something that enhanced HTML's capabilities through a process called compiling) without compiling, is like saying "I want a function to get executed without being called - I hope they fix JS soit can be done" (imo)...

Comment: @ExpertSystem I have edited the question title - what I mean by "without compiling" is "without having to use the `$compile` service myself". And by "composable" I mean directives composed of other directives, as in my case above

Comment: @AlexG: Mybe a fidddle/plunkr would help...