# how to stop angularjs directive's compilation chain?

Tags: angularjs, compilation, angularjs-directive

Check this [plunk..](http://plnkr.co/edit/g9V63fLJt1DP6U6OYbzt).
the `my-dir` directive adds an `ng-model` directive bound to a new scope property and recompiles.
`my-dir` obviously removes itself's attribute to avoid infinite-loop.
It works well except for:
If the element has other directives (e.g. `ng-click`, in the plunk) it gets compiled twice, doubling it's effects.
Is there a way to `"compile my-dir firsts and stop!"`, or wahtever to avoid the issue ?

Comment: try `terminal: true` and  `priority: 1000` on your directive, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs/19228302#19228302

Comment: Yep! that's the way!! Thank you @Khahn TO