# How to create a custom AngularJS directive delegating to ngModel?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Suppose I have something like this:

```html
<div my-custom-root="root">
    <input type="text" my-custom-Path="path.to.somewhere" />
</div>
```

And now I want to translate this to something which essentially behaves equivilant to:

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="root.path.to.somewhere" />
```

I get so far as to specify the two directives, get all the objects etc. These **supply me with the root object and the path, but how do create a binding from those?** I am missing the generation of the appropriate ng-model directive or the use of the [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) directly.

I created a [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PoQkgUVRQdsPJb8hSjsw?p=preview) with the stuff I managed to put together so far.

For easier reference here is my code of the directives just like they can be found in my plunkr as well:

```
app.directive('myCustomRoot', function() {
    var container;

    return {
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.container = function() {
                return container;
            };
        },

        compile: function() {
            return function ($scope, elm, attrs) {
                $scope.$watch(attrs.myCustomRoot, function(newVal) {
                    container = newVal;
                });
            };
        }
    };
});

app.directive('myCustomPath', function($parse) {
    return {
        require: '^myCustomRoot',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs, containerController) {
            var getter = $parse(attrs.myCustomPath);
            scope.$watch(function() {
                    return containerController.container();
                },
                function(newVal) {
                    if (newVal) {
                        alert('The value to be edited is: ' + getter(newVal) + '\nIt is the property "' + attrs.myCustomPath + '"\non Object: ' + JSON.stringify(newVal) + '\n\nNow how do I bind this value to the input box just like ng-model?');
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    };
});
```

You can see that I have all the things available in my alert-Box, but I don't know how to do the binding.

Comment: There's a setter method which pretty much similar to the getter that you have already used...

Comment: @HarishR: You mean the setter for my property? Yes, I could use it to update the value, but I need to do so everytime something in the `<input>` element changes. Yes I could register listeners on the input und do so, but the ng-model directive does all of this. So I hope that I can somehow utilize it.

Comment: seems overly complex to me, you only need the string value of `my-custom-root` so you can set the `ng-model` attribute and compile it

Comment: Can the `my-custom-root` and `my-custom-root` be dynamically changed?

Comment: @charlietfl: Actually I tried that. I inserted `attrs.$set('ngModel', 'some.Path');` at the point where the alert is. When I look at the DOM in Firebug the `ng-model` attribute gets inserted properly but my input box remains empty, even if my model is not. I also tried to make sure that the attribute is created in-time by playing with priority levels and moving the $set() attribute to another position (not inside $watch), but I could not get this to work.

Comment: @runTarm: The string which refers to a property does not change. However the value it refers to my change. Especially the root-object may be loaded asynchronously and may not yet be present when rendering.

Comment: I see, so the `root` and `path.to.somewhere` both are literal strings, not expressions right?

Comment: @runTarm: Well yes, the attribute values themselves are literal strings. Of course at some point they will need to be handled as expression so find the object they refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hoped that there was some way to write `someBindingService.bindInput(myInput, myGetter, mySetter)`, but I have done quite a lot of source code reading and unfortunately the binding  is coupled closely to the compilation.

However thanks to the question "[Add directives from directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs)" I managed to figure out a way which is less elegant but it is compact and effective:

```
app.directive('myCustomPath', function($compile, $parse) {
      return {
        priority: 1000,
        terminal: true,

        link: function(scope, element, attrs, containerController) {
          var containerPath = element.closest('[my-custom-root]').attr('my-custom-root');
          attrs.$set('ngModel', containerPath + '.' + attrs['myCustomPath']);
          element.removeAttr('my-custom-path');
          $compile(element)(scope);
        }
      }
    });
```

This uses a little bit of jQuery, but it should not be to hard to do it with plain jQLite as well.

Comment: You could require `^myCustomRoot` and set/get its attribute in controller, that would eliminate the use of jQuery.

Comment: @runTarm: No I can't. The controller is not available during link-time (if I misunderstood you, plz provide an example)

Comment: Please see `my-custom-path2` directive in this http://plnkr.co/edit/QFDmIXhzaF2plKw2hYpw?p=preview