# AngularJS: Applying directives to all matching tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a large web form that I have built, (over 100 fields) and I want to add AngularJS to enable users to type into the form and run Javascript to store the Angular Model in a database as they type.  Clearly I don't want to send data to the database every time the user alters a tiny piece of data, so I want to use the `ng-model-options` directive to tell Angular to only fire off an `updateOn` after 500ms or so.

I really don't want to apply a huge amount of angular to every `<input>` tag in my HTML though, that's a lot of typing, and if I ever want to change something, it's a lot of places to go through and manually update.  What I'd really like to do is something like `$("input").setDirective()` or somesuch thing if it existed.  I realize I'm thinking about this in a jQuery-type way, so I'm interested to hear the "proper" Angular way of applying the same set of directives to every element in my DOM that matches some selector.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Little modification to @Bodzio answer

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <input type="text" name="something" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" name="different" />
    <input type="radio" name="different" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('input', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
          // filter the element using attributes
          if (attributes.type === "text" && attributes.name) {
              element[0].value = "It works!";
          }
      }
  };
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zjdscakc/1/)**

Comment: This is great, it shows me how to "select" all the `<input>` tags; but I still don't see how to add a directive to that `<input>` tag. Let's say I want to add `ng-model=attributes.name` to all of the `<input>` tags, how can I add that `ng-model` directive to the tag now that I've got it selected?

Comment: If your problem is solved, can you please mark it as an answer :) Or let me the know the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a directive for `<input>` tag like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('input', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, element) {
          element[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
  };
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zjdscakc/

Comment: And to avoid useless call, use an object property as ng-model, like this: ng-model="storage[fieldName]". Add a watcher on the storage in your controller, and if data have changed, set the changeFlag to true. In your setTimeout - if you want to use one -, check if a change appends, and, if true, launch your XHR query and reset the changeFlag :) This way, you are going to call the server only when needed.

Comment: This is great, it shows me how to "select" all the `<input>` tags; but I still don't see how to add a directive to that `<input>` tag.  Let's say I want to add `ng-model=attributes.name` to all of the `<input>` tags, how can I add that `ng-model` directive to the tag now that I've got it selected?

Comment: I don't know is this possible... But you have access to input element (second argument in `link` function), where you can add event listener  for `onchange` event (`element.on("change", function () { ... });`) and do your work without data bindings...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out there was a similar question asked, I just didn't know how to search for it: [Add directives from directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs). Using that as my template, I figured out how to apply new directives to everything containing a custom directive.  I could not figure out how to apply it to all `<input>` tags directly, but adding a `saveme` directive to all my `<input>` didn't take too long. ;)