# Dynamically add/remove directive from an html element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to dynamically remove and add directive to one element in javascript? Why it's not possible to do that with setAttribute() and removeAttribute() if in directive definition there is: restrict: 'A'?

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Comment: setAttribute / removeAttribute only handles string attributes on a dom element. You are trying to manipulate angular outside of angular. I thnik there is a way to notify angular about dom changes done outside of the framewrok, but I'm not sure how its done.

Comment: you need to use $compile if u r adding or removing attribute directives

Comment: @entre, can you find any example of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend the ng-if directive on your element. Take in to account that [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive creates a new scope.

```
<div your-directive ng-if="ctrl.displayDirective" > </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to add a new directive as an attribute

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('parentDirective', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function link(scope,element, attrs) {
        element.attr('child-directive', 'value');
        $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    };
  });
```

read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19228302/1139099)

Comment: Do somebody know how to do this in Angular2+? E.g. to add the core directive ‚formControlName‘ to a component instance.