# loop through the provided attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular, I have a requirement where I need to add many custom attributes to a custom element directive, `<radio-button>`. Currently, I am doing like this:

```
<radio-button one-attr="some value" two-attr="some string" three-attr="some other string"><radio-button>
```

I have many radio buttons on the page and writing custom attributes to each custom directive on that page looks messy. So, I am looking for an alternative where I can pass a javascript array object which loops on each `radio-button` custom directive.

For example: (*In controller*)

```
  $scope.values = [{
       'one-attr': 'some value',
       'two-attr': 'some other value',
       'three-attr': 'another value',
       /* and so on... */
  },
  {
       /* another custom attribute set */
  }
  /* so on */
  ]
```

and then to my custom directive, I will pass an `custom attribute directive` as shown below:

```
  <radio-button ng-repeat="(key, value) in values" loop-attributes="key, value"></radio-button>
```

Where above `loop-attributes` is a custom attribute directive applied to the custom element directive.

Please suggest how to do this.

If I am going wrong please suggest me how to handle this.

Comment: Consider moving that up one more level and have a directive for the group of radios and use `name` in hashmap object to store arrays for values, labels and properties like `ng-model` `ng-messages` etc. Then use child directive in group template for each input

Comment: Can you please provide a small example?

Comment: You would most probably have to use $compile service as radiobutton is a custom directive. You could have a parent directive which has a list of attributes and within the directive create radiobutton element with attributes and then compile it. I will see if i can come up with an example.

Comment: @Bharat thanks. it will be really helpful for me to give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would most probably have to use $compile service as radiobutton is a custom directive. You could have a parent directive which has a list of attributes and within the directive create radiobutton element with attributes and then compile it. Have used input type for example.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7ANndIuHCFaGyjWkw7sa?p=preview

```
// custom element
.directive('customInput', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="text"></input>'
  };
})

//wrapper directive
.directive('customInputAttr', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // This could be set even in controller
      scope.elemAttrs = [{
        'class': 'class1',
        'ng-model': 'input1'
      }, {
        'class': 'class2',
        'ng-model': 'input2'
      }];

      angular.forEach(scope.elemAttrs, function(elemAttr) {
        var customInputElem = angular.element('<custom-input></custom-input>');
        angular.forEach(elemAttr, function(value, key) {
          customInputElem.attr(key, value)
        });

      var elem = $compile(customInputElem)(scope);
      element.append(elem);
      });

    }
  };
})
```

Comment: This is awesome Bharat. :)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a directive that replaces itself with other directives.  You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs) for how to do that.  I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andqpu84/2/) to show you how this works.  The repeat must be on an outer element and not the element containing the directive itself.  This is because your `custom-attr` directive will be parsed before the `ng-repeat` gets parsed, so it won't yet have a value for `attr`.

EDIT:  I left out an import step at the end of the link function, sorry.  [This](http://jsfiddle.net/andqpu84/5/) updated fiddle should work.  You need to recompile the directive to make your added `ng-click` directive actually function.  You also have to make sure to make the function you're binding `ng-click` to available to that scope, either by passing it in or by using `ng-click="$parent.foo()"`

Comment: Can I do the same with `ng-model` and `ng-class` (_as custom attributes_)?

Comment: I think it is not possible to add `ng-model` and `ng-class` http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/andqpu84/3/