# Validation isn't triggered though attributes are set

Tags: angularjs

My directive looks as follows:

```
directive('setAttribute', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                var prop = $scope.$eval(attrs.setAttribute);

                prop.validationRulesToApply.forEach(function (rule) {
                    attrs.$set(rule.name, rule.val);

                });
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can this one is for setting attributes dynamically. In spite of attributes are set properly(i can see them in final HTML) no validation is triggered. When i output $error object with curly braces - it is empty! Do i miss something important when setting attributes?

Comment: You should also include the HTML. The form and input tags all need a `name` attribute for validation to work. Or there could be some other problem lurking there.

Comment: Sure, name attributes are set properly too.

Comment: I guess i need something like rerendering or reinstantiating of an input to be performed,  but can't see a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these validation rules you are trying to add in setAttribute directive?

If it so, you are doing in wrong way. When you use $set, it just adds attribute to HTMl, but doesnot compile them. 
Hence, you won't get results as you are seeking.

You need to add it to pre compile 
I think this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs) may help you.

[Add directives from directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs)