# Conditionally add the "multiple" attribute to ui-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-select

I'm trying to add the `multiple` attribute to a `ui-select` directive based on the value of a certain property using the `ng-attr-` directive. Unfortunately, that's not working for me. I've setup a plunker example to showcase what is happening.

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/10ZtH6xWdwZdI7Ad3MTl?p=preview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Edit

I finally got it after reading through the mentioned [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6950#issuecomment-89730346) in the Angular Repo.

You need to set up a directive with a higher `priority` and a `terminal` attribute set to true (which skips the compilation of all other directives, after the compilation of our directive).
Then in the `postLink` function we will compile the whole element itself. But before that our own directive needs to be removed (infinite loop!).

Big shot outs to [Add directives from directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs#answer-19228302)

#### Directive Code

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('multiSelectChecker', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: false, 
      terminal: true, //terminal means: compile this directive only
      priority: 50000, //priority means: the higher the priority, the "firster" the directive will be compiled
      compile: function compile(element, attrs) {
        element.removeAttr("multi-select-checker"); //remove the attribute to avoid indefinite loop
        element.removeAttr("data-multi-select-checker"); //also remove the same attribute with data- prefix in case users specify data-multi-select-checker in the html

        return {
          pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  },
          post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { 
            if(scope.options.Multiple == true) {
              iElement[0].setAttribute('multiple',''); //set the multiple directive, doing it the JS way, not jqLite way.
            }
            $compile(iElement)(scope);
          }
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

#### HTML Code

```
  <ui-select ng-model="model.choice" multi-select-checker>
    <ui-select-match>{{$item.Title}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item.Id as item in options.SuggestedValues | filter: { Title: $select.search }">
      <div ng-bind="item.Title | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

#### Working Plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/N11hjOFaEkFUoIyeWqzc?p=preview

---

### Original answer (also working, but with duplicate code)

I did the following:

1. Created a wrapping directive called `multi-select-checker`
2. In that directive check wether the `options.Multiple` is true or false
3. Return two different template URLs for each case. Case 1): return single-select.tpl.html or Case 2): return mutli-select.tpl.html (which includes the 'multiple' directive.

#### Directive code:

```
app.directive('multiSelectChecker', function() {
return {
    template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
        if($scope.options.Multiple == true) {
          console.log("multi-select");
          return "multi-select.tpl.html"
        }
        else {
          console.log("single select");
          return "single-select.tpl.html"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

#### Usage in HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <multi-select-checker>
  </multi-select-checker>
</body>
```

#### Template 1: single select

```
<ui-select ng-model="model.choice">
    <ui-select-match>{{$item.Title}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item.Id as item in options.SuggestedValues | filter: { Title: $select.search }">
        <div ng-bind="item.Title | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

#### Template 2: multi-select

```
<ui-select ng-model="model.choice" multiple>
    <ui-select-match>{{$item.Title}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item.Id as item in options.SuggestedValues | filter: { Title: $select.search }">
        <div ng-bind="item.Title | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

As you can see the two templates only differ by one single directive: 'multiple'. Maybe there are better solutions.

I even can't understand, why the ng-attr-multiple approach isn't working.

In addition I have realized, that there are two seperate input fields being rendered via the ng-attr-multiple approach.

And the single selection case seems to be broken (by removing the multiple directive) - which was in your intial Plnkr as well.

#### Working Code

See the working Plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/T9e5tcAkcQLsDV3plfEl?p=preview

Comment: This is a correct solution but I'd like to avoid duplicating code, which is why I tried using the `ng-attr` in the first place. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You could transclude the children of your `ui-select` -> which decreases your repeated code.

Comment: I have investigated further: it seems that the ng-attr-multiple doesn't evaluate (it's content is still "{{options.Multiple}}". I have checked the ui-select code, which checks if the multipe attribute is set - which it is true both for ng-attr-multiple="{{options.Multiple}}" and even setting ng-attr-multiple="" will evaluate to true (as it just checks if the multiple attribute is defined LoC [https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/src/uiSelectDirective.js#L21](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/src/uiSelectDirective.js#L21) - thus being rendered as a multi-select.

Comment: Even some more info on the exact thing what you are trying to achieve: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5524

Comment: With regards to your final solution, if anyone wants to pass a variable from the controller (without using $scope) you need to create an isolate scope and then compile the `$parent`.  Thank you!

Comment: The ui-select itself is using 2 separate templates too. check the code.
`return theme + (angular.isDefined(tAttrs.multiple) ? '/select-multiple.tpl.html' : '/select.tpl.html');`

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want to achieve:

```
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    This works perfectly well:
    <ui-select ng-model="model.choice" multiple>
        <ui-select-match>{{$item.Title}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="item.Id as item in options.SuggestedValues | filter: { Title: $select.search }">
            <div ng-bind="item.Title | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
    <br />
    <br />
    This does not work:
    <ui-select ng-model="model.choice2" multiple="{{options.Multiple}}">
        <ui-select-match>{{$item.Title}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="item.Id as item in options.SuggestedValues | filter: { Title: $select.search }">
            <div ng-bind="item.Title | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
  </body>
```

Comment: Yes but it does not work. Because whatever the value of options.Multiple is, it will always be assumed to be a multiple choice select.

Comment: Yes, I see now. It seems that it is an open issue in angular please check https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7714   and Narretz's answer:  "Binding to multiple is currently not supported. It was forbidden because it caused issues with the select directive."

Comment: Yes, I was using the ng-attr directive to get it to work but it failed. It did add the multiple attribute, but it screwed up the ui-select-match nested directive: apparently, it got compiled before the multiple attribute was added and consequently it behaved like it does in the context of a single choice ui-select. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: I am sorry man, I don't have an idea how to go round this issue. It is not supported by framework.