# How do I remove attributes from an element based on an expression in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on my portfolio site and I've added a slight parallax effect to my header.

You can see this effect here:

http://claytonkinder.github.io/#/profile

It is VERY unfinished at the moment, so I'd advise only looking at it in Chrome.

---

This effect lags terribly on mobile devices, so I'm trying to remove all parallax effects from them.

I've got it working by using ng-show to show/hide different headers depending on if my isMobile variable is true or false, but that's a lot of duplicated code and I think it's pretty sloppy.

This is my complete header code:

```
<header ng-show="!isMobile" parallax-background parallax-ratio="0.2" ng-controller="NavController">
  <div>
    <div parallax parallax-ratio="1.4" parallax-vertical-offset="0" parallax-horizontal-offset="0">
      <h1>Clayton</h1>
    </div>
    <div parallax parallax-ratio="1.15" parallax-vertical-offset="0" parallax-horizontal-offset="0">
      <h1>Kinder</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <nav set-class-when-at-top="fixToTop" add-class-when-mobile>
    <div class="navWrapper">
      <div class="navLeft">
        <div>
          <span>Clayton Kinder</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="https://github.com/ClaytonKinder"><i class="fa fa-github" title="Github"></i></a>
          <a href="tel:843-324-7727"><i class="fa fa-phone" title="Phone"></i></a>
          <a href="mailto:ClaytonAlanKinder@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" title="Email"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navRight">
        <div>
          <a href="#/profile" ng-class="{active: $route.current.activePage == 'profile'}">PROFILE</a>
          <a href="#/projects" ng-class="{active: $route.current.activePage == 'projects'}">PROJECTS</a>
          <a href="#/contact" ng-class="{active: $route.current.activePage == 'contact'}">CONTACT</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The mobile version is exactly the same except for lacking all of the parallax-related attributes, meaning that this:

```
<header ng-show="!isMobile" parallax-background parallax-ratio="0.2" ng-controller="NavController">
```

becomes this:

```
<header ng-show="!isMobile">
```

---

My question is: **what's the best way to get the finished header I'm looking for**? Can I add/remove attributes based on an expression? Can I just do ng-show/ng-if on the beginning header tag and two divs that have parallax effects instead of having to copy over the entire header again?

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: As I understand, its working but you don't want to duplicate code -- is that correct? Are you using a back-end framework for this site? It would be most straightforward to detect mobile on the back-end and serve different HTML depending...

Comment: Yes, that's true. I'm going to bring in Node.js for a simple email form, so I might try it with that. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a directive which will remove itself and add other directives.

Here's a template for you:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive("showWhen", showWhen);

function showWhen($compile, $timeout) {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 1000,
    terminal: true,
    link: showWhenPostLink
  };

  function showWhenPostLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    var listener = scope.$watch(attrs.showWhen, function(condition) {
      if (condition) {
        element.removeAttr("show-when"); // to stop infinite loops after $compile
        // add directives here, ng-disabled is just an example
        element.attr("ng-disabled", "true");
        $compile(element)(scope); // $compile all the newly added angular directives
        $timeout(function() {
          listener(); // unregister the $watch
        });
      }
    })
  }

  return directive;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vnNIRLeW5SvtlVO22SWh?p=preview

Read more @ [Add directives from directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs)

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna give this a shot.

Comment: Glad to be of service ;)