# angularjs binding to an attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-bindings

I am trying to load directive inside another directive dynamically, so I am trying to use `ng-repeat` for the below, where `{{item.directiveName}}` is the inner directive name.

```
<card ng-repeat="item in items" {{item.directiveName}} title="{{item.title}}">
```

The problem is that the `{{item.directiveName}}` is not evaluated, it stays as it is. I think because it is not a value of an attribute, it is an attribute.

Is there any way for this expression to be evaluated or this is not supported by angularjs?

Comment: Angular only will parse item.directivename as an attribute's value, but not as an attribute. You should write a directive to print and manage the whole <card> instead.

Comment: `{{item.directiveName}}` angular only compile once, that syntax won't work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: This should help you: [Add directives from directive in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs)

Comment: @zeroflagL, I update the question

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, depending on the card directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<card  {{item.directiveName}} title="{{item.title}}"> </card>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the card directive coming from?

Comment: it is a custom directive that I developed. Forget about the card directive, you can put a div instead the card directive, and you will face the same problem.

Comment: Is card your directive as well? Anyways, I think this approach would not work because you assign value after the compile stage. For starters, if card is your directive, try adding a breakpoint in its link function and check the attributes and change your html to:
<card  card-type="{{item.directiveName}}" title="{{item.title}}"> </card>

Comment: So you're trying to dynamically load a directive in a directive basically? I don't think Angular will do that out of the box. This codepen: http://jsfiddle.net/ftfish/KyEr3/ should get you pretty close.

Comment: yeah, that is right. I am trying to load a directive inside another directive dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

try to assign it to an attribute

```
<card ng-repeat="item in items" data="{{item.directiveName}}" title="{{item.title}}">

    <card ng-repeat="item in items" myAttr="{{item.directiveName}}" title="{{item.title}}">
```

Comment: If I assign it to to an attribute, it will work, but I do not want to do it, because this is the name of another directive that should be executed.