# Angular appending html with directives from within a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to write a small directive that will append the validation tags and ngMessages dynamically to the input. But I'm having trouble appending the ng-message attribute to the div.

The idea is to have this,

```
<div validator validations="{json_data containing error messages}">
  <input name='fieldName'>
</div>
```

Turned in to the following according to the provided JSON.

```
<div validator> 
  <input required="required"></input>
  <div ng-message="fieldName" ng-if="fieldName.$dirty>
    <p ng-message="required"> scope.message </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've currently managed to get the ng-required appeneded using the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19228302/3156644) answer. But I can't seem to append the ng-message tag using the same technique. What should be done differently to solve this issue?

The final directive should be able to generate something like [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmfn457k/)

The current version can be found in the Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n7uzrets/38/) the example works as expected until 'scope' is added. But as soon as 'scope' is added, the example stops working.

**Update**
I've realized that this only occurse when you add a local scope. This error doesn't occure when using the global scope and accessing the variable using `scope.$eval(attrs.message)`

Comment: Have you actually tried [angular-formly](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly)? if not - checkout, if yes - browser source code

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly thank you for the quick reply. I have tried out angular-formly and found it to be really useful. But I'm doing the development for an organisation that prefers to have an in-house system. What do you mean by 'browser source code'?