# Angular using two way binding on appended and compiled attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm working on attaching html elements with directives from another directive. I've managed to successfully append the html elements with directives using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19228302/3156644) answer.

But, the values added to these elements through the directives don't change with the scope change. For example,

Controller Code:

```
var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.el=2;
};
```

Directive link function

```
link: function link(scope,element, attrs) {
    element.attr('value', scope.el); //sets value to 2 as expected

    element.removeAttr("common-things");

    scope.el = 1 //Does not change value to 1

    $compile(element)(scope);

    //Even changing the scope variable after a timeout, the value remains 2
    $timeout(function(){
      scope.el = 4
    }, 2000); 
  }
```

A working plunker can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/S1t2PlwTX2aUiYZR04pF?p=preview

Running $compile after changing the value works, but it resets all values in the element(ex-Changing an attribute and running compile removes the current ng-value).

How can I bind the values to the scope from inside the directive?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this but the one I would start with would be passing your scope variable through as an isolated scope bound with the = attribute to the inner directive.

Comment: @tuckerjt07 I tried passing the scope through the isolated scope and then triggering function after a timeout still doesn't change the value as expected. (http://plnkr.co/edit/BKIRcvGFbfWdcr26C0vm?p=preview)