# Add custom Directive to existing Input that already has angular directives [ng-model/ng-required]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to use a standard input control that is decorated with `ng-model` and `ng-required` and then add my own custom attribute directive that provides `uib-typeahead` functionality to the control.

I used this link to get my directive partly working.

[Add directives from directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs)

[PLUNKR - The Version 2 of the directive does not work correctly with ng-model](https://embed.plnkr.co/49qRYunWuE4zNWO6PRpA/)

My Directive does add typeahead functionality and that works quite well, but it is not binding the model on to the control after item is selected.

I have two version of my directive.

**Version 1**: is an element style directive and I have been using it successfully for a while, but it fell short when I wan't to have a bit more control over the input element, especially when I wanted to use ng-required='true' and other ng-message directives.

**Version 2**: is an attribute style directive, I went with this because I felt it was better to just add the typeahead functionality that I wanted to any standard HTML that can optionally use `ng-required='true'`, `ng-model` etc...

While this directive is mostly working, it does not interact correctly with `ng-model` and I'm not sure how to get it working

```
angular.module(APP)

.directive('wkLocationSuggest', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    replace: false,
    //terminal: true,
    //priority: 0,
    scope: {
      wkApiModel: '=' // Provide access to the internal data that is returned via the API lookup
    },
    controller: 'LocationSuggestController',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      if (!ngModelCtrl) {
        return;
      }

      element.attr('typeahead', 'location as row.location for row in typeAhead($viewValue)');
      element.attr('typeahead-wait-ms', '750');
      element.attr('typeahead-on-select', 'onSelectInternal($item, $model, $label)');
      element.attr('typeahead-min-length', '2');
      element.attr('typeahead-focus-first', 'true');

      element.removeAttr("wk-location-suggest");        //remove the location-suggest to avoid indefinite loop
      element.removeAttr("data-wk-location-suggest");   //also remove the same attribute with data- prefix if it exists

      // None of this is working
      //// invoked when model changes from the outside
      //ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
      //  //scope.innerModel = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
      //};

      ////// invoked when model changes from the inside
      //scope.onChange = function (value) {
      //  ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.innerModel);
      //};

      scope.onSelectInternal = function ($item, $model, $label) {

        // This fires, but it effects the ng-model on the first input, 
        // but not the input that this directive is attached too
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue($item.location);

      };

      $compile(element)(scope);

    }
  };
}]);
```

**These two images demonstrate part of the problem, may be better to test for yourself using PLUNKR above**

[image: Version 1 & 2 of the directive in action]

[image: Version 2 not working correctly]

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Hope it helps.

Comment: Just reviewing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially tried to *dynamically add validators* to your `wk-location-suggest-new` directive by implementing `blur` on the input element in combination with `ngModel`'s `$setValidity` method; but don't know what exactly was preventing the event from firing.

Therefore, I turned to the other directive `wk-location-suggest-old` and tweaked it a bit to fit in both desired behaviors.

> There, I noticed that you were missing a couple of things:
>
> - First of all, in order for a form element to ***glue*** with the form itself (`wkProfileCompany` in your case), and to work with `ng-model`, the element (*in the directive template*) needs a *name*.
> - Secondly, `ng-required` (or `required`) would work with the form only if it is added as an attribute to the element in the directive template, *not* the directive which compiles to the template containing the element.

### Directive Definition

As you may notice, I've passed two properties from the outer scope to the directive's inner scope, namely:

- the `name` of the input element,
- and an `isRequired` flag as to specify whether the input is *required* or not.

.

```
.directive('wkLocationSuggestOld', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '?ngModel',
    scope: {
      name: '@',      // <==
      isRequired: '=' // <==
    },
    template: '<input name="{{name}}" type="text" class="{{innerClass}}" ng-model="innerModel"'
       + ' ng-change="onChange()" uib-typeahead="location as row.location for row in typeAhead($viewValue)" '
       + ' typeahead-wait-ms="750" typeahead-on-select="onSelectInternal($item, $model, $label)" '
       + ' typeahead-min-length="2" typeahead-focus-first="true" '
       + ' ng-required="isRequired">',  // <== added ng-required here
    controller: 'LocationSuggestController',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) {
          return;
      }          
      ...
}])
```

---

### HTML

Finally, you can use the tweaked directive in your HTML as such:

```
<wk-location-suggest-old class="form-control" type="text" name="location2" ng-model="location2" is-required="true"></wk-location-suggest-old>
```

---

## [***Plunker***](https://embed.plnkr.co/nXqSXwGFVEt1AOBWoimL/)

---

### Update

One of the possible reasons for `ng-model` not correctly binding in the `wk-location-suggest-new` directive to a provided value (*i.e. `location3`*) is that you are replacing the whole `DOM` element with a new custom `DOM` element which is *compiled* with the *isolated* `scope` of the directive itself.

Since the directive `wk-location-suggest-new` has an isolate scope, the scope is totally unaware of `location3`, because `location3` (*and all the other location values*) are defined in the scope of `MainCtrl` and NOT the scope of the directive itself; therefore, you'll end up binding the input's value to an `undefined` property.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
   if (!ngModelCtrl) {
     return;
   }
 ...
$compile(element)(scope); // <== here
```

Comment: Thanks, I would have preferred to get my new version working as it has more flexibility going forward, but I can see the iiss you are talking about with the compilation destroying reference to location3. Thank you for at least finding a solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your model in `setTimout()` like below as you have an isolated scope in the directive.

```
setTimeout(function () {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.location3 = 'Your selected value'
                    });
}, 2000);
```

Alternatively you can also utilize `$timeout` service to achieve the same result.