# Add directives from directive in AngularJS but keep ng-model binded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angular-directive

This question is linked to following question:

[Add directives from directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs)

In suggested answer, there's problem that ng-model is not updating because element is being compiled in directive.
What I expected is that, after I change select option, ng-model will be binded to selected item, but it's not.
Is there any way to fix it?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Tw1Pbt?p=preview

Specificly:

```
  <select ng-options="s for s in selects" ng-model="el" common-things>
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
{{el}}
```

Here ng-model (el) has always same value, no matter what option I choos from select

Same problem is if I have isolated scope inside directive, for instance:

```
         <input type=text common-things ng-model="el.val"                otherdata="something"/>
```

I eexpect, as I write something inside input, that {{el.val}} would have that value, but it's not being updated.

Answer (score 2):

Your additional directive creates a new scope for the `<select>` element. Due to [JavaScript Prototype Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs), the property `el` ends up on the directive's scope rather than the parent controller's scope.  This is a common pitfall, and a major reason to **always use a dot in angular bindings**.

The quick fix for this is to define `el` on the main controller as an object, and set a property of the object.

```
$scope.el = {};
$scope.el.val=2;

<select ng-options="s for s in selects" ng-model="el.val" common-things>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/h443WsCiw6nhlxwY9SSw?p=preview)

Comment: What if I have isolated scope in directive. For instace:
HTML:
 <input otherdata="something"  common-things  type="text" ng-model="el.val">

And I want, base on otherdata value add multiple directives.  Because of that, I have isolated scope in common-things directive, and in that case, ng-model (el.val) is not updated as I write something inside input tag.

Comment: if you make the scope on the input isolate, then not even your `selects` will bind to the element.  If it is necessary to make the scope on an element isolate, then the directive that manages that element must take **total** responsibility for the data being used on that element;  one way to accomplish this would be to bind `ng-model` to the `scope` in the directive.

Comment: Can i make it without isolated scope?
What I am trying to do is:
based on properties of passed data to directive (attribut "otherdata" on input) I want add other directive to that field.
For examply if somedata.required=true, I want add my-required directive.

Aditionally, I want add html tag <span> after my input with following behaviour: I want it to be displayed if some function (from parent scope) evaluates to true. Because of that, I have isolated scope, I don't know how else pass function with parameters to directive and make that function to be called when user change input value

Comment: it seems like you are trying to over-engineer this solution.  what does `my-required` do that the normal `required` wouldn't accomplish?  also, if you want a span after the input, then you probably should either have the span in the HTML separately and use `ng-if` or `ng-show`.  If those don't work, your next best option would be to make a "wrapping" directive, and use transclusion to include the `input` without having the input be the actual target of the directives.