# Enabling checkbox when ng-checked value is False?

Tags: angularjs

I have created an checkbox as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="enableSchedule" ng-model="pr.closed" ng-checked="pr.closed">
```

Now the condition for `"ng-checked="pr.closed"` by default evaluates to false as the value of `pr.closed` is false. but what I want to do is enable the checkbox when the value of `pr.closed` is false and disbaled when the value is `true`.

also the ng-model should be updated accordingly i.e if my checkbox is enabled the value of ng-model should be `true` else `false`.

Comment: Why dont you use ng-disabled to disable checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just negate the `ng-checked` with negation operator !. But since it is advised not to use ng-model with ng-checked, you can use `ng-true-value="false" ng-false-value="true"` to trigger the values of your checkbox based on the value of `ng-model`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="enableSchedule" ng-model="pr.closed"
           ng-true-value="false" ng-false-value="true">
```

```js
angular.module("App",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

  $scope.pr = {closed:false };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="ctrl">
<p>My checkbox:</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="enableSchedule" ng-model="pr.closed"
           ng-true-value="false" ng-false-value="true">
Value of ng-model is {{pr.closed}}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: without ng-model will i get the checkbox value in the controller when the form is submitted?

Comment: You will need ng-model value to get the value of pr.close but it is better if you don't use ng-model with ng-checked. I have update my answer with only ng-model @User101

Comment: @User101 Mark as answer if it helped :)

Comment: thanks very much didn't see your updated answer. this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

change the `checked="!pr.closed"` to check on false.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

  $scope.pr = {'closed':false,"modelval" : true }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input type="checkbox" name="enableSchedule" ng-model="pr.modelval" ng-checked="!pr.closed">checked value is {{pr.closed}} <br>
 model value is {{pr.modelval}}

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('checklist-model', [])
.directive('checklistModel', ['$parse', '$compile', function($parse, $compile) {
  // contains
  function contains(arr, item, comparator) {
    if (angular.isArray(arr)) {
      for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
        if (comparator(arr[i], item)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  // add
  function add(arr, item, comparator) {
    arr = angular.isArray(arr) ? arr : [];
      if(!contains(arr, item, comparator)) {
          arr.push(item);
      }
    return arr;
  }  

  // remove
  function remove(arr, item, comparator) {
    if (angular.isArray(arr)) {
      for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
        if (comparator(arr[i], item)) {
          arr.splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }

  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/19228302/1458162
  function postLinkFn(scope, elem, attrs) {
     // exclude recursion, but still keep the model
    var checklistModel = attrs.checklistModel;
    attrs.$set("checklistModel", null);
    // compile with `ng-model` pointing to `checked`
    $compile(elem)(scope);
    attrs.$set("checklistModel", checklistModel);

    // getter / setter for original model
    var getter = $parse(checklistModel);
    var setter = getter.assign;
    var checklistChange = $parse(attrs.checklistChange);
    var checklistBeforeChange = $parse(attrs.checklistBeforeChange);

    // value added to list
    var value = attrs.checklistValue ? $parse(attrs.checklistValue)(scope.$parent) : attrs.value;


    var comparator = angular.equals;

    if (attrs.hasOwnProperty('checklistComparator')){
      if (attrs.checklistComparator[0] == '.') {
        var comparatorExpression = attrs.checklistComparator.substring(1);
        comparator = function (a, b) {
          return a[comparatorExpression] === b[comparatorExpression];
        };
        
      } else {
        comparator = $parse(attrs.checklistComparator)(scope.$parent);
      }
    }

    // watch UI checked change
    scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue === oldValue) { 
        return;
      } 

      if (checklistBeforeChange && (checklistBeforeChange(scope) === false)) {
        scope[attrs.ngModel] = contains(getter(scope.$parent), value, comparator);
        return;
      }

      setValueInChecklistModel(value, newValue);

      if (checklistChange) {
        checklistChange(scope);
      }
    });

    function setValueInChecklistModel(value, checked) {
      var current = getter(scope.$parent);
      if (angular.isFunction(setter)) {
        if (checked === true) {
          setter(scope.$parent, add(current, value, comparator));
        } else {
          setter(scope.$parent, remove(current, value, comparator));
        }
      }
      
    }

    // declare one function to be used for both $watch functions
    function setChecked(newArr, oldArr) {
      if (checklistBeforeChange && (checklistBeforeChange(scope) === false)) {
        setValueInChecklistModel(value, scope[attrs.ngModel]);
        return;
      }
      scope[attrs.ngModel] = contains(newArr, value, comparator);
    }

    // watch original model change
    // use the faster $watchCollection method if it's available
    if (angular.isFunction(scope.$parent.$watchCollection)) {
        scope.$parent.$watchCollection(checklistModel, setChecked);
    } else {
        scope.$parent.$watch(checklistModel, setChecked, true);
    }
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 1000,
    terminal: true,
    scope: true,
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
      if ((tElement[0].tagName !== 'INPUT' || tAttrs.type !== 'checkbox') && (tElement[0].tagName !== 'MD-CHECKBOX') && (!tAttrs.btnCheckbox)) {
        throw 'checklist-model should be applied to `input[type="checkbox"]` or `md-checkbox`.';
      }

      if (!tAttrs.checklistValue && !tAttrs.value) {
        throw 'You should provide `value` or `checklist-value`.';
      }

      // by default ngModel is 'checked', so we set it if not specified
      if (!tAttrs.ngModel) {
        // local scope var storing individual checkbox model
        tAttrs.$set("ngModel", "checked");
      }

      return postLinkFn;
    }
  };
}]);




var app = angular.module("app", ["checklist-model"]);
app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope) {
  $scope.roles = [
    'guest', 
    'user', 
    'customer', 
    'admin'
  ];
  $scope.user = {
    roles: ['user']
  };
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
    $scope.user.roles = angular.copy($scope.roles);
  };
  $scope.uncheckAll = function() {
    $scope.user.roles = [];
  };
  $scope.checkFirst = function() {
    $scope.user.roles.splice(0, $scope.user.roles.length); 
    $scope.user.roles.push('guest');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl1">
   <label ng-repeat="role in roles">
  <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role"> {{role}}
</label>

    </div>
```